# Saving NLA-Strip Configurations for Multiple Actions for further Animation

Tags: animation, armature, nla-editor

Is there a way to save NLA-Strip Configurations like this?

Here is whats going on in the scene:

- walkcycle from left to right
- look around with the head and other acting
- tail wave
- jump over obstacle
- tail dynamics made by spring bones addon

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want a single action to perform all animation programmed using NLA.

To do so, select all bones involved in the animation (if exporting, you can select deforming bones only), in pose mode go to pose menu > animation > bake action.

Using its preferences you can create a new action based on all the previous programming (check all preferences except overwrite current action in the exporting scenario).